# can ansible run multiple playbooks same time?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
- name: "API"
hosts: api
vars:
   platform: "{{ application.api }}"
vars_files:
- vars/application-vars.yml
tasks:
 - include: tasks/application-install.yml

- name: "JOBS"
hosts: jobs　
vars:
   platform: "{{ application.jobs }}"
vars_files:
  　- vars/application-vars.yml
tasks:
　  - include: tasks/application-install.yml
```

playbook like before described, can I execute this　difference tasks on difference hosts in the same time as parallel way?

Comment: what's the reason to make separate equal plays for `api` and `jobs`?

Comment: JOBS platform should be  platform:"{{application.jobs}}", isn't same play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure what do you actually want, but I'd combine it into single play:

```
- hosts: api:jobs
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/application-install.yml
```

And add group vars to inventory:

```
[api:vars]
platform="{{ application.api }}"
[jobs:vars]
platform="{{ application.jobs }}"
```

This way you can run your playbook on all hosts at once, and also you can use `--limit` option to choose `api` or `jobs` group only.

Answer (score -2):

you can run more playbooks using "ansible-playbook [OPTIONS] *.yml" command. This will execute all the playbooks NOT IN PARALLEL WAY, but in serial way, so first one playbook and after the execution, another playbook. This command can be helpful if you have many playbooks.

I don't know a way to execute more playbooks in parallel.